# How do I split a string in groups of 2 characters in powershell without delimiters?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, split

I have a problem where I accept a string of number. I need to split the string into group of 2 numbers and perform arithmetic operations on them. I am aware of powershell -split operator but it doesen't work as intended. Preferably I would like them to be split into array of 2 characters or integers.

Example:
$inputdata=1234302392323

Output:
12
34
30
23
92
32
3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `split` operator for this, and cast the array elements to int  like:

```
[int[]]$result = '1234302392323' -split '(..)' -ne ''
```

$result will be an array of ints:

```
12
34
30
23
92
32
3
```

Comment: Nicely done; just to offer the generalization with an arbitrary number of characters, such as `3`: `'1234302392323' -split '(.{3})' -ne ''`