# Is it possible in PowerShell to split a 4096 character variable into equal 1024 character parts?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, powershell, split

I have seen this done in other languages, but I have not been able to achieve this yet in PowerShell.

I am attempting to read in a device's HardwareID for importing into Azure. The HardwareID variable is 4096 characters, and I can only store a max of 1024 characters per variable in this program....

is there a clean way to break a random-character 4096 string into equal 1024 char parts?

I have tried using regex, with the split-string command, and with the -spilt option, but I don't know enough regex to get a working query...

```
$devDetail = Get-CimInstance -NAmespace root/cimv2/mdm/dmmap -ClassName MDM_DevDetail_Ext01 -Filter "InstanceID='Ext' AND ParentID='./DevDetail'"

$devDetail.DeviceHardwareData -split "^.{1,1024}$"
```

That doesn't seem to work like I hoped... Any awesome hints for me to get this working?

Note:

- **$devDetail.DeviceHardwareData** is a random char string, I am unable to split this on a specific pattern or character, which I think the Split command was designed to be used for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, without binding to the beginning `^` or end `$` of the string; parentheses preserve the delimiter.  Based on [How do I split a string in groups of 2 characters in powershell without delimiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61445696/how-do-i-split-a-string-in-groups-of-2-characters-in-powershell-without-delimite/61446162#61446162)

```
$devDetail.DeviceHardwareData -split '(.{1024})' -ne ''
```

Small example:

```
'123456789012' -split '(.{3})' -ne ''

123
456
789
012
```